# How do I migrate my site without doing a direct DB export and site upload?

Tags: 7, migrations, importing-exporting

I'm in an odd situation. When I try moving my site from my dev server to my production server the whole thing blows up. I think it is something in my database, it even happens if I export the DB with all but the core modules turned off.

So what then is the best way to export my site (nodes, users, views, panels, contexts et al) to the production server then?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole thing blows up"? Content missing, theming messed up?

Comment: UI messed up, paths broken, content parts missing…

Comment: UI will always get messed up, theme cache has to be rebuilt thats all. But can you provide more info on paths & content.

Comment: Paths blow up, I get 404s on /admin or /?q=admin for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

After removing some content that wouldn't make it to the main site, I did the following:

- I manually installed all the same modules.
- I used [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) to deploy the majority of my data types.
- I used [Field Collection Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_deploy) to copy my field collections over (while the entity itself can be copied via Features, the fields it contains are not!).
- I used [Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) to copy over most of my nodes (there were some nodes that were not importable due to errors, this is likely part of the problem I was having).
- Recreated other user.

New site seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 2):

What you should have done is remove sites/all/default/settings.php; 
Now copy and rename the: 
sites/all/default/default.settings.php => sites/all/default/settings.php

Phase 2
 
Migrate the database to the production server
Phase 3 
Copy the drupal directory from your dev to production server
Phase 4
On the production server hit the following Your_Domain_Name.com/install.php
follow the install instructions and set the database settings and you will be redirected to your site with config.
Phase 5
run cron to make sure eveything is running ok and update if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your htaccess is set correctly, and sometimes you need to manually configure Apache AllowOverride All settings for your directories.
Also try clearing the cache tables in the DB.